# Checking if first portion of an environment's content is empty

Tags: environments, expansion, enumitem, nesting, answers

**Motivation**: I am working on a very personalized *Exercise/Answer* package for my colleagues. The `exercise`, `exsheets`, etc. packages don't do what I need.

To accomplish this, I create an `exercises` environment along with `\question` and `\subquestion` commands. They are used nested within one another in that order (see code below for example use).

---

**The code**: The following code compiles (I know, it's a long MWE):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}


%% New lists to use with enumerations (enumitem)
\newlist{lquestion}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[lquestion,1]{label=\textbf{\arabic*.}, labelsep=0mm, leftmargin=0mm, nosep, parsep=0mm, align=parleft, resume=lquestion}

\newlist{lsubquestion}{enumerate}{1}
%% NOTE: itemsep and parsep must be equal
\setlist[lsubquestion, 1]{label=\textbf{\alph*)}, labelsep=.8em, leftmargin=*, nosep, topsep=0mm, itemsep=1mm, parsep=1mm, resume=lsubquestion}


%% Define new environment `exercises` and new commands `\question` and `\subquestion`
\makeatletter
\newtoggle{cgexer@bool@hasquest}
\newtoggle{cgexer@bool@hassubquest}
\toggletrue{cgexer@bool@hasquest}
\toggletrue{cgexer@bool@hassubquest}

%% Environment `exercises`
\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercises}{s O{}}
  {%% Before
    \global\togglefalse{cgexer@bool@hasquest}%% NO QUESTIONS YET
  }%
  {%% After
    \iftoggle{cgexer@bool@hasquest}%
      {%% THE EXERCISE BLOCK CONTAINS QUESTIONS...
          \end{lquestion}
      }{}%
  }

%% Used within command `\question` to check whether text is provided before the first `\subquestion`
\newtoggle{cgexer@bool@hasgeneralquest}
\NewEnviron{preparegeneralquest}{%
  %% Was text specified within `\question{...}`, before the first `\subquestion`?
  \ifdefempty{\BODY}{}{\global\toggletrue{cgexer@bool@hasgeneralquest}}
  \BODY%% Show the specified text
}

%% Command `\question`
\NewDocumentCommand{\question}{s O{} +g +g}{%
  \global\togglefalse{cgexer@bool@hasgeneralquest}%% NO TEXT (GENERAL QUESTION) SPECIFIED BEFORE FIRST `\subquestion` YET
  \global\togglefalse{cgexer@bool@hassubquest}%% NO `\subquestion`s YET
  \nottoggle{cgexer@bool@hasquest}%
    {%% FIRST QUESTION...
        \begin{lquestion}[start=1]
        \global\toggletrue{cgexer@bool@hasquest}%% THE EXERCISE BLOCK NOW CONTAINS 1+ QUESTION(S)
    }{}%
  %
  \vspace{12pt plus 2.0pt minus 1.5pt}
  \item START%% ***REPLACE WITH: \item \begin{preparegeneralquest}%
      #3%% Show the content of the question (including all `\subquestion`s)
  %
  \iftoggle{cgexer@bool@hassubquest}%
    {%% THE QUESTION CONTAINS SUB-QUESTIONS...
        \end{lsubquestion}
    }%
    {%% THE QUESTION DOES NOT CONTAIN SUB-QUESTIONS...
        STOP%% ***REPLACE WITH: \end{preparegeneralquest}%% To close \begin{preparegeneralquest}
    }%
}

%% Command `\subquestion`
\NewDocumentCommand{\subquestion}{s O{} +g +g}{%
  \nottoggle{cgexer@bool@hassubquest}%
    {%% FIRST SUB-QUESTION...
        STOP%% ***REPLACE WITH: \end{preparegeneralquest}%% To close \begin{preparegeneralquest}
        \begin{lsubquestion}[start=1]
        \global\toggletrue{cgexer@bool@hassubquest}%% THE QUESTION NOW CONTAINS 1+ SUB-QUESTION(S)
    }{}%
  %
  \item #3%
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\begin{exercises}
  \question{Question 1
      \subquestion{Sub-question A}
      \subquestion{Sub-question B}{Sub-answer B}
      \subquestion{Sub-question C}{Sub-answer C}
      \subquestion{Sub-question D}
      \subquestion{Sub-question E}{Sub-answer E}
  }{Answer 1}

  \question{Question 2}

  \question{Question 3}{Answer 3}

  \question{Question 4
      \subquestion{Sub-question A}{Sub-answer A}
      \subquestion{Sub-question B}
      \subquestion{Sub-question C}
      \subquestion{Sub-question D}{Sub-answer D}
      \subquestion{Sub-question E}
  }{Answer 4}

  \question{
      \subquestion{Sub-question A}{Sub-answer A}
      \subquestion{Sub-question B}
      \subquestion{Sub-question C}
      \subquestion{Sub-question D}{Sub-answer D}
      \subquestion{Sub-question E}
  }{Answer 4}
\end{exercises}


\vspace{2\baselineskip}

\makeatletter
Testing the \verb|preparegeneralquest| environment:

\textbf{Test 1}:

\togglefalse{cgexer@bool@hasgeneralquest}
\begin{preparegeneralquest}
  This one contains text.
\end{preparegeneralquest}
(\textbf{\iftoggle{cgexer@bool@hasgeneralquest}{Text was provided}{No text provided.}})

\textbf{Test 2}:

\togglefalse{cgexer@bool@hasgeneralquest}
\begin{preparegeneralquest}
\end{preparegeneralquest}
(\textbf{\iftoggle{cgexer@bool@hasgeneralquest}{Text was provided}{No text provided.}})
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

---

**Output**: The generated output is...

[image: Output for the above code sample]

---

**The issue**: For layout reasons, I have to identify whether or not some text has been specified within `\question{...}` before the first `\subquestion` is encountered (if any).

To accomplish this, I've tried to use the `environ` package along with the `\NewEnviron` and `\BODY` commands to gather the text and check (with a new environment called `preparegeneralquest`) whether it is empty or not using `\ifdefempty` (I have tried using the `ifmtarg` package, but it fails in this context and I don't know why; possibly due to expansion?).

Now since the `\subquestion` commands are nested within the `\question` command, I've attempted to do this by *forcing the insertion of* `\begin{preparegeneralquest}` and `\end{preparegeneralquest}` at the appropriate places in the structure. This is accomplished by changing the three lines identified with `*** REPLACE WITH:` in the code provided above, i.e. by changing

```
\item START
```

for

```
\item \begin{preparegeneralquest}%
```

and (twice, because it appears at two different places)

```
STOP
```

for

```
\end{preparegeneralquest}
```

However, after doing this, the document fails to compile and gives the error messages:

```
\begin{preparegeneralquest} on input line 92 ended by \end{exercises}
[...]
! Undefined control sequence.
\env@preparegeneralquestion@parse ...name #1\env@nil
                                                     \csname env@preparegeneral...
```

and so on.

---

**Question**: What am I doing wrong and is there a good way to trace what's happening (e.g. through a .tmp file)? Using the above version of the code, the `START` and `STOP` text is typeset at the appropriate place, but I understand it could be a nesting issue when this text is changed for an environment.

Nota:

- I wouldn't mind using a command `\preparegeneralquest` instead of an environment, but then I get bracketing issues that I don't seem to be able to solve using `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` (or the much scarier `\bgroup` and `egroup` for that matter).
- If you are wondering why I'm creating new commands `\question` and `\subquestion` instead of simply defining them as lists with `enumitem`, it's because they will have various arguments, including a list of key-based options using `pgfkeys`.

Comment: Have you looked at `xparse`?

Comment: Might I ask what you had in mind? I'm using it for the `\NewDocumentCommand` macro and I've used it before for key-values, but I prefer `pgfkeys` for that task, lately. I don't know how the `\NewDocumentEnvironment` macro could help me in this situation (possibly through `amsmath`'s `\collect@body`, or even better through `environ`'s `\Collection@Body`, but I've never used either).

Comment: It was just a thought... But if you really need to do it that way, likely not a useful one.

Comment: Checking `environ`'s `\BODY` should work... probably not with `\ifdefempty`, though, as an environment body easily contains blanks if nothing else.

Comment: Can we assume that the argument of `\question` always contains at least one `\subquestion`?

Comment: @egreg: alas, no, which is the hard part. In the example code provided above, questions 2 and 3 contain no `\subquestion`s. I'd say both cases (with or without `\subquestion`s) arise as often in practice.

Comment: @cgnieder: any suggestions? I've tried `\@ifmtarg` (`ifmtarg` package), but it doesn't seem to work. I had the impression there was some kind of expansion issue, but I'm not very comfortable with TeX's expansion process yet.

Comment: If you want to check if the environment body contains nothing but possibly spaces then `etoolbox`'s `\ifblank` comes to mind: `\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\BODY}{true}{false}`